# How do I handle DSBPOSITIONNOTIFY events?

Tags: c++, directsound

I have created a server and client in C++ that play music. I am now trying to create notifications that specify when the sound buffer playback has reached one quarter or three quarters of its size.

```
//Create event handles
LPDIRECTSOUNDNOTIFY8 directSoundNotify;
HANDLE playEventHandles[2];
playEventHandles[0] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
playEventHandles[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

buffer->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectSoundNotify8, (LPVOID*)&directSoundNotify);

//Assign handles to DSBPOSITIONNOTIFY array
DSBPOSITIONNOTIFY positionNotify[3];
positionNotify[0].dwOffset = bufferSize / 4; //One quarter of the size
positionNotify[0].hEventNotify = playEventHandles[0];
positionNotify[1].dwOffset = bufferSize - (bufferSize / 4); //Three quarters of the size
positionNotify[1].hEventNotify = playEventHandles[1];
directSoundNotify->SetNotificationPositions(1, positionNotify);
directSoundNotify->Release();

buffer->SetCurrentPosition(0);
buffer->Play(0, 0, 0);

//Wait for notifications
WaitForMultipleObjects(2, playEventHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);

if (/*First notification occurs*/)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (/*Second notification occurs*/)
{
    //Do something else
}
```

What should I put in the if statements at the bottom of the code in order to determine when the notifications have occurred? Or should I handle the notifications using something other than if statements? If so, how can I handle the notifications and determine if they have occurred?